# how to enable remote desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I was recently setting up my Linux pc to be able to run as a NAS on the local network, and I noticed that when I right click on the machine in the network list on windows I get the option to remote desktop the machine.

I clicked this, and after a while of it trying to load nothing happened. presumably, I have to enable something on my device first. what do I have to change and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable remote desktop on your Ubuntu, follow the steps personally followed by me on Ubuntu v16.04 LTS:

- Search your computer and type `desk` to open desktop sharing
- Enable `Allow other users to view your desktop` option if you want other users should just see your desktop. To give them editing rights also, opt for `Allow other users to control your desktop` option
- Google for different VNC clients and find the one that suits you the best
- Combine `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `t` keys together to open a fresh terminal window
- For connection, I personally use `remmina` command
- **Security setting**

In case someone tries to connect with you and you want to check before blocking or allowing that connection, check the `Ask you for confirmation` option.

You can also `set up a password for your remote connection` to avoid giving anyone unauthorized access to your system.

Comment: is it possible to do just with the terminal? the only easy way I have to access the system is ssh.

Comment: I have always used this brother. But I am sure there would be other ways too. Let's see what other experts here have to say. We can always learn from them.

Comment: if you don't know a way, then I may as well just connect the machine up, it's just that I only have 1 set of peripherals. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: let me know how it goes. May be your experience makes me try it too at my end. Regards.